# Intuitive meaning of a totally bounded set

Tags: general-topology

By definition, a totally bounded set is always covered by some finite collection of equal-sized open balls. Is it possible to obtain an intuitive meaning from this definition? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much @DougM! In fact, I am studying metric spaces.

Comment: @DougM, I address your sentence *You can say that a set is totally bounded if the maximal distance between any two points is finite.* This means boundedness in the ordinary sense.

Comment: Totally bounded is a "smallness" or a "wideness" condition on a metric space. While completeness is a "gap" or a "hole" condition on a metric space.

Comment: Can I say that a totally bounded set has a finite size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such cover should exist for any size. Look at the following interpretation (in a metric space). Choose arbitrarily $\varepsilon>0$. There exist $x_1,\dots,x_n$ - the centers of the balls of our cover. Let $y$ be any element of our set. Then $y$ lies in some ball which means that $y$ lies $\varepsilon$-close to some $x_i$. This is, in fact, an $\varepsilon$-net.